# Instagram graph api: how get more information?

Tags: instagram

i get mentions instagram and i have this json

```
{
  "entry": [
    {
      "changes": [
        {
          "field": "mentions",
          "value": {
            "comment_id": "17903590462155058",
            "media_id": "17869029877213819"
          }
        }
      ],
      "id": "17841407409822844",
      "time": 1521014423
    }
  ],
  "object": "instagram"
}
```

How can I get more information for this mention, such as `url`, `post`, `instagram`, `user` etc. to understand who writes to me?

```
17841407409822844?fields=mentioned_comment.comment_id(17903590462155058)
```

This request above for additional information does not give me the right data to build a link to the post, it returns the fields:

```
id
like_count
media
text
timestamp
user
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more information about the media, you can access it like this:

`17841407409822844?fields=mentioned_comment.comment_id(17903590462155058){media{media_url,permalink,username}}`